# Weird media query (max-width) behavior

Tags: css

I've been stuck on the following problem for a while now.

```html
@media screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* appropriate code */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* appropriate code */
}
```

The issue I have is that when a screen is on the specific width of 767px, no styling is applied. What really confuses me is that on the other hand the specific width of 600px does work, while both are the max-width value of their respective media query. I have had this issue with other similar media queries but decided to simply provide you with those two to make my problem clear. I have tried out several things (verifying zoom value of browser, trying on different browser) but it doesn't seem to work. At first I thought it might be a bug but it's a recuring problem. Do any of you have an idea as to what might be the problem?

Comment: Probably the device resolution isn't 767px. Check the real device resolution, or set 768px breakpoint. Given pseudocode is okay.

Comment: do you have any style rules for screens more than 767px? Do this happen for all devices or for a particular device/browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's working correctly on my side. But for more accuracy, you can use decimal values like so.

```css
/*                    414 -> 413.7             600 -> 600.3             */
@media screen and (min-width: 413.7px) and (max-width: 600.3px) {
  div {
    color: red;
  }
}


/*                    601 -> 600.7             767 -> 767.3             */ 
@media screen and (min-width: 600.7px) and (max-width: 767.3px) {
  div {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

When min-width is used, it means the lowest width and styles are set for the higher width

When max-width is used, it means the maximum width and styles are set for the width less than that

When both are used, styles are applied when the width between the values is entered

Comment: So what's the problem with the code?

Comment: OP is trying to figure out, why the styles won't be applied to specific values.

Comment: I've found out that this weird behavior only occurs when the max-width behavior ends on an uneven number, I did several tests and never get this issue with values ending on an even number, very wierd... .